# ubuntu 17.10 problem with mobile broadband

Tags: internet, 17.10, broadband

When I upgrade ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10, mobile broadband detected but not connected !! Am trying to reinstall 17.10 but I found the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The new GUI interface didn't work for me at all.  But this did:

```
# check status of broadband device (on or off)
nmcli radio wwan

# turn it on (if off)
nmcli radio wwan on

# bring up my broadband connection, which I've called "My Broadband"
nmcli connection up "My Broadband"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I downgrade modemmanager to vesion 1.4.12-1ubuntu1 and the modem got connected. ubuntu 17.10 comes with an upgrade to modemmanager so I'm not sure if I was missing something with that version but that solved my problem. I hope this can help.